# Splash screen problem?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Hi I have created a splash screen but I am not sure how to get it to start.  I have tried putting it in the top folder but I can't get it to start, I realise this is because it is the last item I created on my app.

How do I get it to the top of the build path.

Comment: I won't be able to help you with this as Android is still on my To Do list, however others may find it easier to help you if you can provide more information on what you've done and perhaps samples of your code/xml config.

Comment: Have you set the config in your manifest file such that the Splash Screen is the first Activity to be launched?

Comment: How would I do this, I just added stuff as I go along, aplolgies for the noobness

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you placed your Splashscreen in your manifest.
Should place your Splashscreen as the first activity and then the main activity.
For eg:
**//First Activity as Splashscreen**

activity android:name=".SplashScreen"

```
 android:screenOrientation="portrait"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

**//Splashscreen activity ends here**

**Your main activity followed by remaining activities.**

```
    <activity android:name=".Aptv"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            action android:name="com.ayansys.aptv.Aptv" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```